# Compare names between columns in R

Tags: r

The data I have look more or less like this:

```
data1 <- data.frame(col=c("Peter i.n.","Victor Today Morgan","Obelix","One More"))
data2 <- data.frame(num=c(123,434,545,11,22),col=c("Victor Today","Obelix Mobelix is.",
                    "Peter Asterix i.n.","Also","Here"))
```

I would like to match names across the two dataframes and get the column `num` into data1.

Desired outcome:

```
                   col  num
 1          Peter i.n.  545
 2 Victor Today Morgan  123
 3              Obelix  434
```

I have tried this, but doesn't work as expected.

```
filter <- sapply(as.character(data1$col), function(x) any(grepl(x,as.character(data2$col))))
data1$num <- data2[filter,]
```

Comment: In data2, the number on Peter's row is 545, but in your desired outcome Peter has a number of 123. Is this correct?

Comment: What is your criteria for matching the 'col' columns? Some sort of fuzzy match, or containing the same words, or what?

Comment: just match the first name `(Peter,Victor,Obelix)` and get the corresponding `num` value of each from `data2` to `data1`

Comment: @James. I'm sorry!Now corrected. The name `Peter Asterix...` from data2 corresponds with number `545`(third row) so that should match with `Peter i.n.` from `data1`.

Comment: @Michael. I think matching the first word would suffice.

Comment: You could potentially do it your way, but you"ll get the col names of `data2` instead of `data1`. Something like `data2[as.logical(sapply(gsub(" .*", "", as.character(data2$col)), function(x) any(grepl(x,as.character(data1$col))))),]`

Comment: This solution is good too since I would not mind which columun of `data1` or `data2` is taken, I just need the correposing column `num`. Thanks!

Comment: I'll post it as an alternative answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
firstName <- function(x) sub(" .*", "", x)
data1$num <- data2$num[match(firstName(data1$col), firstName(data2$col))]
data1[!is.na(data1$num),]
```

Comment: I also played around with `match`: like this: `data1$num <- data2$num[match(data1$col, data2$col)]` ,but obviously the `sub` part was missing here!Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind which `col` names you wan to see (`data1` or `data2`), you could utilizes your own solution by:

```
data2[as.logical(sapply(gsub(" .*", "", as.character(data2$col)), function(x) any(grepl(x, as.character(data1$col))))), ]

##   num                col
## 1 123       Victor Today
## 2 434 Obelix Mobelix is.
## 3 545 Peter Asterix i.n.
```

This will match the first word in `data2$col` to `data1$col` and retrieve the correct entries out of `data2`